# Não consigo fazer o Firebase Cloud Messaging notification funcionar no navegador web

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Eu estou bem perdida em como fazer as notificações funcionarem. Acho a documentação deles muito confusa. Mas seguindo até onde entendi e alguns tutoriais, acho que consegui resolver uma boa parte e deve estar faltando pouca coisa.

Vou passar tudo que ja fiz:

**No primeiro plano na pagina inicial está assim:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
    var config = {
    apiKey: "meu api key",
    authDomain: "meusite.firebaseapp.com", // Tenho dominio próprio e não sei se devo colocar ele aqui.
    databaseURL: "https://meusite.firebaseio.com", // Não sei pra que serve isso.
    projectId: "meusite",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "470112242644" // Não lembro da onde eu tirei esse número.
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('plugins/firebase/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then((registration) => {
        messaging.usePublicVapidKey("um key que uso que tbm não lembro de onde tirei");
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

        messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
           console.log('Notification permission granted.');
           if(isTokenSentToServer()){
               console.log('Token ja salvo.');
           } else {
           getRegToken();
       }
       }).catch(function(err) {
         console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
       });
  });
  function getRegToken() {
        messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
          if (currentToken) {
            saveToken(currentToken);
            console.log(currentToken);
            setTokenSentToServer(true);
          } else {
            console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            setTokenSentToServer(false);
          }
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
          showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
          setTokenSentToServer(false);
        });
  }

  function setTokenSentToServer(sent) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('sentToServer', sent ? '1' : '0');
  }

  function isTokenSentToServer() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('sentToServer') === '1';
  }

  function saveToken(currentToken) {
      // Enviar Token para firebase database
  }

  messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log('Mensagem Recebida ', payload);
       notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
       notificationOptions = {
          body: payload.data.body,
          icon: payload.data.icon,
          image: payload.data.image
        };

        var notification = new Notification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  });
</script>
```

Até aqui eu consigo pegar o token do navegador, mas não sei aonde armazenar. No Tutorial que eu vi, eu teria que colocar num banco de dados meu, mas depois enviar msg um por um. E acho q isso eu teria problemas pra mandar msg pra mais de 100 mil pessoas que solicitarem as notificações. Então pensei que seria melhor fazer por **tópicos**, mas nem imagino como se faz, e gostaria muito de uma ajuda com essa parte.

No arquivo serviceworker **firebase-messaging-sw.js** está da seguinte forma:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');
    var config = {
    apiKey: "meu api key",
    authDomain: "meusite.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://meusite.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "meusite",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "470112242644"
  };
// Até aqui tenho as mesmas duvidas do script na pagina inicial, e nem sei se precisa mesmo repetir tudo assim

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
var messaging = firebase.messaging();

// [START background_handler]
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    image: payload.data.image
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
// [END background_handler]
```

Eu tentei testar pelo console do firebase, mas não consegui receber nenhuma mensagem, acho que não esta dando certo. Fiz um script em php e tbm não deu certo de enviar msg.

O Script em php está da seguinte forma **FireBaseNotifications.class.php**:

```
class FireBaseNotifications {
    private $serverAPiKey = "meu server key";
    private $tokens = [];
    private $firebaseurl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    public function setServerAPiKey($serverAPiKey) {
        $this->serverAPiKey = $serverAPiKey;
    }

    public function setTokens($tokens) {
        $this->tokens = $tokens;
    }

    public function SendNotification($icon, $titulo, $mensagem, $image) {
        $msg = ['icon'=>$icon, 'title'=>$titulo, 'body'=>$mensagem, 'image'=>$image];
        $payloads = ['registration_ids' => $this->tokens, 'data' => $msg];
        return $this->CurlExecute($this->firebaseurl, $payloads);
    }

    private function getHeader() {
        return ['Authorization: Key='.$this->serverAPiKey,'Content-Type: Application/json'];
    }

    private function CurlExecute($url, $postfields) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postfields),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $this->getHeader()
        ));

        $result['response'] = curl_exec($curl);
        $result['err'] = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Eu criei essa classe sozinha e nem sei se fiz certo, gostaria de adaptala para aceitar topicos ou dispositivos, mas não sei como faz. Se alguém tiver alguma ideia e puder me orientar, eu agradeceria muito.

E pra usar o link acima eu faço assim:

```
$fbcn = new FireBaseNotifications();
$fbcn->setTokens(["token do usuario 1", "token do usuário 2"...]);
$fbcn->SendNotification("linkDeImagemDoIcone.jpg", "Titulo da Mensagem", "Minha Mensagem", "linkDeImagemdaNotificacao.jpg");
```

Mas nada disso está funcionando ainda. Estou totalmente perdida. E tudo que encontro na net está em inglês. E o que encontro em portugues é só pra aplicativo android, não encontro nada para versão web.

Alguém poderia me ajudar e me explicar um pouco melhor sobre como funciona e como trabalhar com topicos e dispositivos?? ♥♥

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, mas assim funcionou:

Na mina index:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var config = {
    apiKey: "[sua api]",
    authDomain: "[ seu domain]",
    databaseURL: "[ tanto domain quanto essa são opcionais, mas eu coloquei ]",
    projectId: "[ seu prject id]",
    storageBucket: "[ storage]",
    messagingSenderId: "[ seu sender]"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
// Add the public key generated from the console here.
messaging.usePublicVapidKey("[sua key ]");
messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  vai();
  // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
  // ...
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
var vai = function (){
  messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log(currentToken)
      //sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      //updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
      // Show permission request.
      console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    //showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
    //setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });
}
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  // Messages received. Either because the
  // app is running in the foreground, or
  // because the notification was clicked.
  // `payload` will contain your data.
  console.log("Message received. ", payload);
  var notification = new Notification(payload.data.title, {
      icon: '[ logo]',
      body: payload.data.message,
    });
notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("[ link a abrir]");      
    }
});
</script>
```

na firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```html
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
  var config = {
    apiKey: "[ sua key]",
    authDomain: "[ domain]",
    databaseURL: "[ url]",
    projectId: "[ projeto]",
    storageBucket: "[ storage]",
    messagingSenderId: "[ SENDER ID]"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    image: payload.data.image
  };
return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,notificationOptions);
});
```

por algum motivo sempre chama o "firebase-messaging-sw.js" na raiz do localhost, então da uma conferida nisso tbm

seu php ta mais organizado que eu o meu, mas o meu ta assim:

```html
<?php
$to="[tokem que vai receber]";
$title="Olá! :D";
$message="Teste de Notificação :D";
sendPush($to,$title,$message);

function sendPush($to,$title,$message)
{
// API access key from Google API's Console
// replace API
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', '[chave do servidor]');
$registrationIds = array($to);
$msg = array
(
'message' => $message,
'title' => $title

// you can also add images, additionalData
);
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
'data' => $msg
);
$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder, eu so vi sua resposta hoje. Me desculpa a demora. 
Eu vou dar uma olhada no seu codigo com mais calma e ver depois onde que estou errando. Ai volto aqui pra responder se deu certo ok?? Obrigadaaa